# Restore from backup | MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have restored from a backup on a specific date to a test server database and I want to check if it restored all the data. How can I check or compare the data between the test database and the production database.

Comment: If it  is on the same server, Simply Left join the originbal data base and ckeck if there a row with Id = NULL

Comment: @nbk No, It's not on the same server. Also the database is very large I don't think that a simple select will guarantee the restored backup.

Comment: First take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/federated-storage-engine.html  so you become the second table available. The try to make a select that i suggested with only a few 100 rows to test the query and then do it from mysql command if it takes very long. Problem is you can use in clause on big tables

Answer (score 0):

**Welcome**.

This would have become a good post (for several others) if you had added little more details.

**Assumptions**.

1. Original database at first server is bigger and the restored database in second server is a subset (backup on a specific date).
2. So many databases, so many tables, so many columns and so many rows.

**Solutions**.

1. Your backup (bet it through your own script or through a tool) should have an accompanying log file. Refer the same for any errors / warnings.
2. Refer the outcome of your restore too. And if both does not have any thing unusual, you can be sure of (may be 95%).
3. Prepare a script to have output from both servers having **group**ed sum values based on important criteria / categories / group heads / etc.
4. Also run this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html on both servers.